# Oracle tips/principles/further reading for an MS Access developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, plsql

I was tasked with converting a full-fledged MS Access application that I created into an Oracle application. The Access database includes about a dozen tables and another dozen queries, including some VBA logic I had to use to rank things efficiently. I've also got forms with VBA behind them to run the queries. My goal is to re-create this application on an Oracle server, setting up the same kinds of tables and queries, and using Application Express for user input. This is not going to be an environment with many users, but there could at times be 2-3 people accessing the same database.

My question is: as a developer of MS Access applications, can you recommend any quick guides (as opposed to full books) that can expose me to the major differences in design and approach in developing an Oracle application? I'm thinking of things like stored procedures, views, transactions, and things like that that aren't available in MS Access. In the end, I'll need to know how to have different users use forms to edit and import data to the database as necessary, and to run the same queries and generate an output table specific to each user (so not writing to the same table each time).

Comment: Sorry, boss, you gotta do the hardwork to learn a technology. We cannot tell you how to learn Oracle Advanced PL/SQL in 24 Hours, go buy a few books and spend some time on them, you'll find it fun. Plus, Oracle has an entire library for your reference at docs.oracle.com.

Comment: Just curious: If this is just a 2-3 user database what is the reason for porting the whole thing to Oracle? If there is concern over a Jet/ACE back-end then you could always use Oracle as the back-end (although SQL Server [Express] might be a tighter fit) and keep the front-end in Access (and save yourself *a lot* of re-work).

Comment: It's the demand of a client. We offered to put just the tables and queries in Oracle and make an Access front-end, but ultimately they want a fully web-accessible (i.e., from a browser) environment. I'm pretty sure they have a number of firewall issues that could inhibit their ability to connect to the Oracle database using Access. In any case, what the client wants the client gets.

Comment: @user1102199 I see it all the time. Usually that's what they *think* they want until they find out how much it's going to cost. Anyway, good luck with the conversion, and be prepared for a learning curve when working with Oracle. It's... umm... *different*. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you have to do here is build an Oracle Application Express system, with no experience of Oracle? That's a really big issue.

The differences between a file-based system like MS Access and a "proper" RDBMS like Oracle are enough to keep you learning for a long time.

If you're going to do a good job of this then you have to start by learning about Oracle, and I'd recommend that you start with the documentation: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage

Specifically, read the concepts guide front-to-back: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=server.112/e25789/toc.htm

Then at least have a good look through the SQL Reference, because data types, table and index types, and the SQL functions are very different to MS Access:  http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=server.112/e26088/toc.htm

Then have a go at the 2 day Apex Developer's Guide: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=appdev.112/e11946/toc.htm

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much - just what I was looking for! Of course, I'll still be looking through anything else people suggest. I'm a quick learner, and this doesn't need to be perfect. In any case, our application is pretty basic in the scheme of things.